# find method received two times while expected once

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have encountered an error while writing some specs

```
QuestionsController GET #edit finds question to edit
     Failure/Error: Question.should_receive(:find).with("#{question.id}").and_return(question)
   (<Question(id: integer, title: string, body: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, up_votes: integer, down_votes: integer) (class)>).find("9")
       expected: 1 time
       received: 2 times

class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

spec/controllers/questions_spec.rb

```
  describe QuestionsController do
    describe 'get edit' do
      it 'finds question to edit' do
        question = create(:question)
        user = create(:user)
        sign_in user
        Question.should_receive(:find).and_return question
        get :edit, :id => question.id
      end
      it 'renders edit template' do 
        question = create(:question)
        user = create(:user)
        sign_in user
        Question.stub(:find).and_return question
        get :edit, :id => question.id
        expect(responce).to render_template 'edit'
      end
    end
  end
```

I use Rspec, Factory Girl, database_cleaner, Postgres

database_cleaner config in spec_helper

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do |group|
    # The strategy needs to be set before we call DatabaseCleaner.start
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

I am testing edit action. i set expectation on Question to receive find in first example and stub find method call in second. i am getting an error in first example
I think these two examples are not fully isolated from each another.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to correspond to the spec. First, the error message starts with 'GET #edit' while the spec starts with 'get edit'. Second, the expectation in the error report has a `with` clause while the spec does not.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing a PUT request:

```
put :edit, id: question.id
```